# Custom error message for the "file required" in zf2

Tags: file-upload, zend-framework2

This is config for the input factory:

```
'name' => 'file',
'type' => 'Zend\InputFilter\FileInput',
'required' => true,
```

When I submit the form without "file" there's no error showing up saying something like "the field file is required". However, if I add the "error_message" the error is showing up, but it overrides other error messages from other validators in this input. When working with regular inputs I add the following validator:

```
[
    'name' => 'not_empty',
    'options' => [
        'message' => 'Field is required'
     ]
]
```

But, I can't do this with FileInput.

Is there any way to set the custom message for the required field in case if "FileInput" is used?